# Ajax modalpopupextender not popping up

Tags: asp.net, ajax, popup, modal-dialog, modalpopupextender

```
    .modalBackground
    {
        background-color: Gray;
        filter: alpha(opacity=70);
        opacity: 0.7;
    }

    .modalPopup
    {
        background-color: #ddffdd;
        border-width: 3px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: Gray;
        margin-top: 60px;
        padding: 2px;
        width: 400px;
        font-size: 10pt;
    }

<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" CancelControlID="Button3"
    OkControlID="btnOk" TargetControlID="LinkButtonDummy" PopupControlID="PanelPopUp"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
<asp:Panel ID="PanelPopUp" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Add New Organisation" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

I have also included the AJAX reference and  a ScriptManager on the master page.

I have to add an enhancement to an existing page and I'm quite new with ASP.NET, the page in question is a 'content page' and is linked to  a master page (containing the scriptmanager).

This code all looks completely fine and I have been reading on this for over three hours now but to no avail - my modal doesn't 'pop-up' and grey the background out, it simply appears where I have placed it on the page (right at the top, or right at the bottom e.t.c.) as if I was just showing/hiding a div.

Can anyone help, I'm going crazy?

What other routes can I go down for adding a confirmation box on a page that takes a string built in the code-behind and also runs code-behind functions on OK/Cancel?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your css as it it and try this code :

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
            <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="MyPopup" runat="server" CancelControlID="Button3" OkControlID="btnOk" PopupControlID="PanelPopUp" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True"  
                TargetControlID="HiddenField1"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

and on Button2_Click event add

```
  MyPopup.Show();
```

Comment: but the button2 click is the confirmation from the pop up, by the time the user can press this the popup should have already happened?

Comment: Then add line at where you want to popup to be appear, may be at page_load event